# Assign response to local variable throws Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, variables

I am using the below script to load data from my api and show locations on the google maps,

The problem is when I assign the response from the api to the local variable `locations` the it doesn't work and the browser console says "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

When I define the locations manually it works fine.

```
var locations = [{
        "_id": "5f3de313b94dd30a984dadcc",
        "uname": "sudesh",
        "__v": 0,
        "lat": 6.903413,
        "lng": 79.884888
    }];
```

How can I assign the response to this `location` variable

This is the code I have used

```
<script>
    var locations;

    // var locations;
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall").then(function(response) {
        
        locations= response;
        return response.json();
        
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("Booo");
    });
    /**
     * Create new map
     */
    var infowindow;
    var map;
    var red_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
    var purple_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';
    
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9271, 79.8612),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);


    var markers = {};

    // console.log(locations);

    var getMarkerUniqueId = function(lat, lng) {
        return lat + '_' + lng;
    };

    var getLatLng = function(lat, lng) {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    };


    var i;
    var confirmed = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
            map: map,
            icon: locations[i][4] === '1' ? red_icon : purple_icon,
            html: "<div>\n" +
                "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +


                "<td><a>User:</a></td>\n" +
                "<td><textarea disabled id='manual_description' placeholder='Description'>" + locations[i].uname + "</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "</div>"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                confirmed = locations[i][4] === '1' ? 'checked' : 0;
                $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed, locations[i][4]);
                $("#id").val(locations[i][0]);
                $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
                $("#form").show();
                infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
</script>
```

> reponse from API

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f3de313b94dd30a984dadcc",
        "uname": "sudesh",
        "__v": 0,
        "lat": 6.903413,
        "lng": 79.884888
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f3de9d9b94dd30a984e644e",
        "uname": "saman",
        "__v": 0,
        "lat": 6.952149,
        "lng": 79.86721
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to parse the json first and then assign the value
so your assignment should be on the second then

second, `then` keyword means wait for something to complete and then do

so anything in then has not been run when you do the loop

the loop need to wait for the api, therefor it should also be in the then closure

```
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall").then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
        
    }).then(function(data) {
        var locations = data;
/**
     * Create new map
     */
    var infowindow;
    var map;
    var red_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
    var purple_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';
    
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9271, 79.8612),
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);


    var markers = {};

    // console.log(locations);

    var getMarkerUniqueId = function(lat, lng) {
        return lat + '_' + lng;
    };

    var getLatLng = function(lat, lng) {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    };


    var i;
    var confirmed = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
            map: map,
            icon: locations[i][4] === '1' ? red_icon : purple_icon,
            html: "<div>\n" +
                "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +


                "<td><a>User:</a></td>\n" +
                "<td><textarea disabled id='manual_description' placeholder='Description'>" + locations[i].uname + "</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "</div>"
        });
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("Booo");
    });
    

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                confirmed = locations[i][4] === '1' ? 'checked' : 0;
                $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed, locations[i][4]);
                $("#id").val(locations[i][0]);
                $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
                $("#form").show();
                infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a few options here:

```
async function() {
   var { res } = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall");
   return JSON.parse(res);
}

// OR
function getLocations() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var locations = fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall").then(res => res.json());
    locations ? resolve(locations) : reject(null);     
  });
}
getLocations()
.then(data => {
    // loop
})
.catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
```

also, in your loop use a `?` to prevent error

```
for (i = 0; i < locations?.length; i++) {
    // logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Location is being assigned value in a promise, so your loop needs to wait until it gets a response from the promise.

You can use [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) instead.

Or you can use the following

```
function createNewMap(locations) {
  /**
   * Create new map
   */
  var infowindow;
  var map;
  var red_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
  var purple_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9271, 79.8612),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);


  var markers = {};

  // console.log(locations);

  var getMarkerUniqueId = function (lat, lng) {
    return lat + '_' + lng;
  };

  var getLatLng = function (lat, lng) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  };


  var i;
  var confirmed = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][4] === '1' ? red_icon : purple_icon,
      html: "<div>\n" +
        "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
        "<tr>\n" +


        "<td><a>User:</a></td>\n" +
        "<td><textarea disabled id='manual_description' placeholder='Description'>" + locations[i].uname + "</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
        "</table>\n" +
        "</div>"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
      return function () {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        confirmed = locations[i][4] === '1' ? 'checked' : 0;
        $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed, locations[i][4]);
        $("#id").val(locations[i][0]);
        $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
        $("#form").show();
        infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}

var locations;

// var locations;
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/user/getall").then(function (response) {

  locations = response;
  return response.json();

}).then(function (data) {
  createNewMap(data);
  
  console.log(data);
}).catch(function () {
  console.log("Booo");
});
```

To understand async processing, you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) out.